# Get values of 'model.fit' keras API parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to get detailed information of the Kera sequential model using a customized callback function. I need to extract all values of the parameters set in `model.fit()` API such as `batch_size`, `epochs`, `validation_split`, etc. But I could not access them in Keras's callback. Do you have any idea how can I get these values automatically?
I am using **Python 3.10** and **Keras 2.8**.

Comment: I don't think you can get these values, unless you pass them manually, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am working on an automatic ML model analysis tool. I need to extract these values automatically to analyze the model in the next step.